# Problem with legend on a 2 y-axis line & ybar figure

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, legend, dateplot

I cannot seem to figure out a way to switch the legend symbol to the ybar symbol in a two y-axis plot. Here is a minimal working example of my problem

Which yields this:

[image]

So the only problem with the figure is that I want to switch the Plot 1 legend image to be that of the default ybar chart. I have tried fiddling around with the `\addlegendimage` command but that didn't seem to work. Anybody have a solution for this? To code used is available below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{pgfplots} 
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
date,rate,install
2012-01-01,48.84,24.4299855
2012-02-01,48.84,173.5773958
2012-03-01,48.84,110.7117086
2012-04-01,22.59,17.4220445
2012-05-01,22.59,36.01732503
2012-06-01,22.59,64.42770708
2012-07-01,22.59,197.822088
2012-08-01,17.22,14.8125984
2012-09-01,17.22,18.78518356
2012-10-01,17.22,44.10470415
2012-11-01,16.11,25.922787
2012-12-01,16.11,21.39109775
2013-01-01,16.11,24.72410623
2013-02-01,16.11,27.6975024
2013-03-01,16.11,33.65679443
2013-04-01,16.11,51.21122378
2013-05-01,16.11,36.79503848
2013-06-01,16.11,67.02365677
2013-07-01,15.54,33.01713989
2013-08-01,15.54,40.61720797
2013-09-01,15.54,38.26365551
2013-10-01,15.54,44.52759475
2013-11-01,15.54,44.36376502
2013-12-01,15.54,42.85926874
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
    scale only axis,
    date coordinates in=x,
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    xticklabel={\year},
    date ZERO=2010-01-01,
    xmin=2012-01-01, xmax=2014-01-01,
    width  = 0.9*\textwidth,
}

\begin{axis}[
  axis y line*=right,
  axis x line=none,
  ymin=0, ymax=200,
  ybar=1*\pgflinewidth,
  bar width=4pt,
  ylabel=Y-axis 2
]
\addplot[red,fill=red,opacity=1]
table [x=date, y=install, col sep=comma] {data.csv}; \label{plot1}
\addlegendentry{Plot 1}
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
  axis y line*=left,
  ytick style={draw=none}
  ymin=0, ymax=50,
  ymajorgrids = true,
  xlabel=,
  ylabel=Y-axis 1,
]
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot1}\addlegendentry{Plot 1}
\addplot[blue]
table [x=date, y=rate, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\addlegendentry{Plot 2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `pgfplots` is using the default plot style for the legend of `plot1` when its inserted into the second plot. Therefore, you should specify the style for the legend in the `\addplot` of `plot1`. Note that there was a [bug reported](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/42/) in this usage mechanism, so both `ybar` and `ybar legend` have to be specified in the `\addplot` options. The bug also requires the `xshift=0.5em` in the `\addlegendimage` line. These suggestions are from Christian on that bug report.

I've also changed 2 things about this code:

1. Switch to `compat=1.12`, the newest version
2. Delete the `\usepackage{tikz}`, since `pgfplots` loads `tikz` anyways.

---

```
\documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots} %graaphien tekoon
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
    \usepackage{filecontents} %tiedostonhallinta? littyy pgfplotsiin
    \usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
date,rate,install
2012-01-01,48.84,24.4299855
2012-02-01,48.84,173.5773958
2012-03-01,48.84,110.7117086
2012-04-01,22.59,17.4220445
2012-05-01,22.59,36.01732503
2012-06-01,22.59,64.42770708
2012-07-01,22.59,197.822088
2012-08-01,17.22,14.8125984
2012-09-01,17.22,18.78518356
2012-10-01,17.22,44.10470415
2012-11-01,16.11,25.922787
2012-12-01,16.11,21.39109775
2013-01-01,16.11,24.72410623
2013-02-01,16.11,27.6975024
2013-03-01,16.11,33.65679443
2013-04-01,16.11,51.21122378
2013-05-01,16.11,36.79503848
2013-06-01,16.11,67.02365677
2013-07-01,15.54,33.01713989
2013-08-01,15.54,40.61720797
2013-09-01,15.54,38.26365551
2013-10-01,15.54,44.52759475
2013-11-01,15.54,44.36376502
2013-12-01,15.54,42.85926874
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
    scale only axis,
    date coordinates in=x,
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    xticklabel={\year},
    date ZERO=2010-01-01,
    xmin=2012-01-01, xmax=2014-01-01,
    width  = 0.9*\textwidth,
}

\begin{axis}[
  axis y line*=right,
  axis x line=none,
  ymin=0, ymax=200,
  ylabel=Y-axis 2
]
\addplot[red,fill=red,opacity=1, ybar=1*\pgflinewidth, bar width=4pt, ybar legend]
table [x=date, y=install, col sep=comma] {data.csv}; \label{plot1}
% \addlegendentry{Plot 1}
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
  axis y line*=left,
  ytick style={draw=none}, %poistaa ytickit joten toi grid näyttää paremmalta
  ymin=0, ymax=50,
  ymajorgrids = true,
  xlabel=,
  ylabel=Y-axis 1,
]
\addlegendimage{refstyle=plot1, xshift=0.5em}
\addlegendentry{Plot 1}
\addplot[blue]
table [x=date, y=rate, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\addlegendentry{Plot 2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my other bar graphs I have the default ybar legend image that looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/BDjIyII.jpg). Would it be possible to get that somehow?

And thank you for your previous answer already!

Comment: @Cadbon I tried adding `ybar legend` instead of `area legend`, but it gave a very strange symbol... you can try it yourself and see, but I don't know how to fix that. Sorry! I'll try to look some more :-)

Comment: @Cadbon It seems there is a bug in pgfplots, I found the bug report and used Christian's recommended work around. See my updated answer :-)

Comment: thank you so much! You're an absolute life saver. I would've never figured this out on my own...